# How to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on property of item in ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

Working with xamarin platform. I need to basically bind a property of an item in observablecollection to label.text property.

So far I have this

MODEL

```
public class TelemetModel : BaseItem , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int dayCount;

    public int Daycount
    {
        get { return dayCount; }
        set
        {
            if (dayCount != value)
            {
                dayCount = value;

                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    public double Tdyattnd { get; set; }
    public double Tdybnk { get; set; }

    public double Tomattnd { get; set; }
    public double Tombnk { get; set; }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
```

ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<TelemetModel> OtelemetInstance { get; set; }
OtelemetInstance = new ObservableCollection<TelemetModel>();

//In some method
var otelemet = new TelemetModel
            {
                Daycount = classcount,
                Tdyattnd = Math.Round(tdyatnd, 2),
                Tdybnk = Math.Round(tdybnk, 2),
                Tomattnd = Math.Round(tomatnd, 2),
                Tombnk = Math.Round(tombnk, 2)
            };
OtelemetInstance.Clear();

OtelemetInstance.Add(otelemet);
```

View

```
lbl_classinfo.BindingContext=ViewModel.ClassVMInstance.DatesVMInstance.OtelemetInstance[0].Daycount;
lbl_classinfo.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ".",converter:new IClassNeededConverter());
```

Right now my view is not updating even though i have used the inotifypropertychanged interface in the model properties.

Spent the better half of 3 days looking for my specific need ie. implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on property of item in ObservableCollection , could not find a snippet anywhere. Im new to MVVM what i have done might be wrong , thanks in advance for helping. Let me know if you need any details.

EDIT:

Iv made a GitHub repo [Here](https://github.com/zany1/Inotify-on-item-prop-of-observcoll)

Comment: I think there is a couple of things wrong with your code, but it would be a bit too extensive to go into. I would just recommend having another good look at MVVM and what problem it tries to solve. From what I see you know how to use the MVVM principles, but you don't fully understand why things are done a certain way. Anyhow, in regard to your problem, try to switch the two lines in your view, so the `lbl_classinfo.BindingContext` and `lbl_classinfo.SetBinding`

Comment: @GeraldVersluis well I couldn't find a single example on how to implement the said title using MVVM, have to probably look upon mvvm deeper. I don't think it will make any difference if I switch those lines I have used them the exact same way many times all of them work. It's just that I'm not sure how to implement inotifypropertychanged on a model. Thanks for the info I was just curious if I had made a small mistake, but I need to just follow a certain way.

Comment: In this case, the order could matter. By setting the BindingContext the object will reevaluate all bindings. Anyhow, that is one of the things I have doubts about. Normally, you would set the BindingContext to a model and from there bind to a property of that, not bind directly to that property by setting the value in the BindingContext. More like this: `lbl_classinfo.BindingContext=ViewModel.ClassVMInstance.DatesVMInstance.OtelemetInstance[0]; lbl_classinfo.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Daycount",converter:new IClassNeededConverter());`.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Iv tried that too, iv tried all the obvious things. Iv went as far as monitoring the event, but it remains null no matter what.

Comment: Is it possible to get this code to me? Or at least a reproduction project?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Alright il whip up a reproduction but how to share it with you?

Comment: Can you put it on GitHub? Or put it somewhere I can download it and send me a message at gerald@verslu.is